# php datetime format error

Tags: php, datetime, format

I try to convert a variable (integer of 8 digits) to date format 
here is my code :

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $data[1])->format('d-m-Y');
```

I get this error :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object
```

any help please ?

Comment: Your script is fine. You should check that `$data[1]` contains what you're expecting it to.

Comment: data[1] contains the value 20010103. when I replace it manually it works and displays 03-01-2001 !!! any idea ?

Comment: Please `var_dump($data[1])` and provide us with results.

Comment: Also please show the code where you're setting $data[1]. That's most likely where the problem is, or you're overwriting it somewhere later.

Comment: var_dump($data[1]) gives string(4) "DATE"

Comment: while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                                    $num = count($data);
  // $date= \DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd',(string)$data[1] )->format('Y-m-d');
                                         // if (new DateTime($date) > new DateTime($_POST["date_from"]))
                                            var_dump($data[1]);
                                            $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $data[1])->format('d-m-Y');
                                             echo '<td>'.$date.'</td>';

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand the code in a comment since it's not formatted properly, but `string(4) "DATE"` shows that `$data[1]` doesn't contain a properly formatted integer. You should debug the code where you set `$date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `$data[1]` doesn't have valid data:

```php
if ($date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $data[1])) {
    echo $date->format('d-m-Y');
} else {
    echo "Input date '{$data[1]}' is invalid.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, The loop takes the first row too where there are strings. that was my mistake. the code is fine. thx guys